# What do I need in order to name devices in a home network? (No IPs)

Tags: ip, ethernet

This question may be super basic, but I don't know a lot about networking and I've been struggling for quite some time.

In my home network (*cable modem/router, couple of switches, and an access point*), the router as usual assigns IP addresses to the various devices, however I don't want to remember all the numbers. I want to be able to **access these devices through a name instead of an IP address**. For example, my printer is assigned `192.168.0.12` and I want to access it through a name such as: `\\MyPrinter` from my laptop running Windows.

How do I accomplish this in the most **economical and easy way** possible without having to setup a Windows Server and what is the name of the hardware and/or software that does this naming functionality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 - DNS Server**

You need a DNS server to resolve a name, 'MyPrinter', to an IP address '192.168.1.9'.

If you have a spare computer, you can install linux (free) with Bind9 (also free) and run your own DNS server from home. Assign the DNS server an IP like 192.168.1.2.

Then on all your devices at home, you would change the DNS server entry to 192.168.1.2.

For example, MyPrinter will have an IP address of 192.168.1.9, a subnet of 255.255.255.0, a gateway 192.168.1.1 (router), and a dns server of 192.168.1.2.

The link below can help you configure your DNS server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

**Option 2 - Local DNS**

The easier option, if you only have one or two PCs at home is to use your Windows computer to do DNS for you. There's a file called 'hosts' that you can edit and create static entries.

An example of the hosts file could be:

```
MyPrinter 192.168.1.9
```

Now, your computer will know where MyPrinter is on the network. However, the limitations to this is - it will only work from your PC. No other computer or device will understand MyPrinter since the hosts file is only on your PC. However, you can copy this file to your other PCs.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I apologize I didn't see this answer before. Your explanation helped me understand better what DNS is for and how to enable it. I recently bought a Netgear ReadyNAS 312 and Bind9 can be installed as one of its apps, however, it's very difficult to setup and Netgear doesn't seem to care for the quality of these apps. I guess I'll have to resort to the Linux approach. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to use names instead of IP addresses is called [Domain Name System (DNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). This is how names like `superuser.com` get resolved on the internet, and this is also how you can use names in your home network.

Many router/modem boxes already have a DNS server capability (you didn't tell us which router/modem you use). So try to configure your router/modem to use it. Additionally, every computer in your home network you want to have a name should get the same IP address every time. Again, that is a feature that many router/modem boxes already have.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response and I apologize I didn't answer any sooner. Unfortunately, most router/modem boxes do have IP assignments, but lack DNS. I have an Arris SURFboard Cable Modem & WiFi Router Model SBG6900-AC and although it looks fancy and all, it doesn't have a DNS built in, and the manufacturer apparently doesn't update the firmware... at least not in months.

Answer (score -1):

Every device in your network will have a name that can be accessed via `\\MyPrinter` or `\\Storage`.  In Windows, you configure this name when you set up the computer, when you give it a name.  If your computer has a name you don't like, then it can be renamed by going to system properties:

1. Open File Explorer.
2. Right Click Computer/This PC (case dependent on your version of Windows)
3. Select Properties.
4. You will see a header that states `Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings`, and under that, `Change Settings`.  Click `Change Settings`.
5. The box the pops up will have the button `Change` next to "To rename this computer or change its domain or workgroup, click Change".  Click `Change`.
6. The next box will have a field to input the new computer name.  Input the new desired name, and click change.  You will be prompted that you will have to restart the computer for the change to take effect.  Hit ok.
7. Hit Ok again, and you will be asked if you want to restart now or later.  Restart if you are ready for the changes to take effect.

When it comes to printers, NAS boxes, or similar hardware, they are pre-programmed with a name.  For example, a printer will have the brand, make, and model number as its name.  Changing the network name of said devices will vary from device to device.

To access file shares on your network, open File Explorer, and type `\\DeviceNameHere` into the location bar.

For more information, here is an article on [Unified Naming Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Comment: You should quote all relevant information, and in detail, explain how to assign names to the author's devices.

Comment: @ServiceManager, I really appreciate all this good info. However, not all devices on my network are Windows computers. I have an AV receiver, a WiFi access point, a couple of mobile phones, tablets, a Skype modem, 2 printers, etc. Logically there must be some kind of table where there are IPs versus friendly names somewhere... but, what is the name of it, and what form it must be in? Is it just software installed somewhere? Most likely a combination of hardware and software. I could find more info on my own if I knew what to look for.

Comment: You don't need special software for this, as companies have been making network resource sharing easier for the last few years.

One thing you can do, is open File Explorer, and select the Network option on the left.  Your device should be listed in the window on the right, and may also show under Network on the left.

If the devices are not directly hooked up to the network (for example a printer hooked up to another computer) then that computer will have to share it.